# Changing font size on scrolling scroll view

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I'm trying to change the font size of a textview based on the ScrollY value of a scrollview.

```
scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged() {

            scrollY = scrollView.getScrollY();

            if(scrollY>0) {

                Log.e("scroll ", "" + scrollY);
                textView.setTextSize(50 - 20*scrollY);
                textView.requestLayout();

            }
        }
    });
```

This works really erratically, the font size does change but randomly, is there a way to get it to change smoothly?

Comment: For anyone stuck on this, this can be solved by  scrollView.smoothScrollBy(1,0); and reducing the scale of scrollY by dividing it by a suitable number.

Comment: I'm struggling with a similar problem. Is it possible to get a posted solution. Then you can accept your solution as your answer to this question.

Comment: Have you found any solution on this ?